# apply if else condition using dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, databricks

With below code I can see the data, there is one row and two columns.
I want to do a selection:

1. if both columns are 0 then do something
2. if both are greater than 0 then do something.

I am getting error in if condition. Can anyone please help me to this done?

> Comment: OP post example dataset here or URL

```
from pyspark.sql import * 
import pandas as pd
query = "(Select empID, empDept from employee)"

df1 = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=query, properties=properties)
df1.show()

if df1[empID]==0 && df1[empDept]==0:
    print("less than zero")
elif df1[empID]>0 && df1[empDept]>0:
    print("greather than 0")
else 
    print("do nothing")
```

Comment: *"I am getting error in if condition"* It'll help those trying to help you if you include said error in your question.

Comment: People like to read a little first and then dive into the code. I've added the location where you need to provide a small example dataset to test against. This can also be an URL in your case where you get the dataset from (up to you to decived; but be aware that the question needs to be a working example to where it goes wrong for others). Hence, include the essentials of the traceback you get as well ..somewhere in your question (likely at bottom).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntactical errors in your script. Try the below-modified code.

```
import numpy as np
if np.sum((df1["empID"]==0) & (df1["empDept"]==0)):
    print("less than zero")
elif np.sum((df1["empID"]>0) & (df1["empDept"]>0)):
    print("greather than 0")
else: 
    print("do nothing")
```

Please note that any comparison on data frame columns( like df1["empID"]==0 ) would return a series of boolean values, so have to handle them as a series not a regular variable.

df1:

```
    empID  empDept
0   1       1
```

Output:

```
greather than 0
```

Comment: Getting erorr: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: it's working fine in my environment, could be something to do with the version of Python / Pandas/ numpy you are using.

I'm using Python 3, Pandas (0.23.4) and numpy (1.15.1)

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your spelling:

1. replace the `&&` with `and`
2. `else:` (the ':' is missing)

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = np.array([[0, 0]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)


if df1.loc[0, 0]==0 and df1.loc[0, 1]==0:
    print("less than zero")
elif df1.loc[0, 0]==0 and df1.loc[0, 1]>0:
    print("greather than 0")
else:
    print("do nothing")
```